# Carly Comando - Everyday. Do I need to use right pedal?

Tags: digital-piano

I am currently learning such a beautiful song like Everyday by Carly Comando. I have Kawai CN24 at home. The way it sounds is different from the original song that is why I have some concerns that probably I do not use pedal properly. Could you help me to figure out do I need to use right pedal? According to music sheet, I couldn't find this information however on YouTube I can clearly see that it is used but again, result sound is completely different even though I am playing correct notes.

Please, advise me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every bar/chord change needs to be pedaled using the right pedal. This, on an acoustic piano, will keep the notes sounding after you've lifted your fingers off. On a digital type piano, it'll have the same sort of effect, but produced differently. Some pedals are not that effective.

Watching a youtube version of this, you can see the dampers on a grand piano lifting as the pedal is pressed. The timing of proper effective pedaling is an acquired art, and it's far easier to have a teacher explain the process. Lots of self-taught piano players pedal badly, and the result is a mushy sound.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for you reply. Does it really matter whether I push pedal to the ground or a little bit? I can hear the difference in sound the way I push the pedal, but still it's not easy to reproduce again.

Comment: On all acoustic pianos, the amount the pedal is depressed makes a big difference. On some electrics, there will be a 'half pedal' arrangement. It's equivalent to JUST lifting the dampers, but only just. If the jack plug is TRS it'll be that sort. You'll have to experiment to find the spot. But for this song, full pedaling will be fine.